# Adding a 4k image to google maps in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a detailed image of a google maps area. The map area is 136ft by 360ft and the image is a 4k image.

How do I add that big of an image to such small area, in google maps to my android activity without crashing of a memory shortage ?

The reason is that I need to track the users' location in a small area, and give them detailed stats about the current location. (Lets say a Photoshop-ed image of a caravan park as a detailed map).

Thank you

Comment: Google "android subsampling imageview" to get started.

Comment: Thank you, It helped a lot with the big images. How would I implement it with google maps api? I just want the location marker of google maps on the image?

Comment: Split image to 256x256 pixels tiles, than use custom `TileProvider`.